# Rust struct can borrow "&'a mut self" twice, so why can't a trait?

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

The following Rust code [compiles successfully](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=367d4b8d4cb1b2010cd10bfc9173ca69):

```
struct StructNothing;

impl<'a> StructNothing {
    fn nothing(&'a mut self) -> () {}

    fn twice_nothing(&'a mut self) -> () {
        self.nothing();
        self.nothing();
    }
}
```

However, if we try to package it in a trait, [it fails](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c515e0c8c5b2d2f83efbca9d034ea2c):

```
pub trait TraitNothing<'a> {
    fn nothing(&'a mut self) -> () {}

    fn twice_nothing(&'a mut self) -> () {
        self.nothing();
        self.nothing();
    }
}
```

This gives us:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/lib.rs:6:9
  |
1 | pub trait TraitNothing<'a> {
  |                        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
5 |         self.nothing();
  |         --------------
  |         |
  |         first mutable borrow occurs here
  |         argument requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'a`
6 |         self.nothing();
  |         ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

- Why is the first version allowed, but the second version forbidden?
- Is there any way to convince the compiler that the second version is OK?

### Background and motivation

Libraries like [`rust-csv`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv) would like to support streaming, zero-copy parsing because it's 25 to 50 times faster than allocating memory (according to benchmarks). [But Rust's built-in `Iterator` trait can't be used for this](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2i6xry/can_i_write_zerocopy_parsers_with_iterator_it/), because there's no way to implement `collect()`. The goal is to define a `StreamingIterator` trait which can be shared by `rust-csv` and several similar libraries, but every attempt to implement it so far has run into the problem above.

Comment: Changing `fn nothing(&'a mut self)` to `fn nothing(&mut self)` fixes the issue. Do you really need this lifetime specifier given your function returns nothing ? Yet, it does look like a bug.

Comment: Levans: Yeah, without that lifetime specifier, the rest of the design falls apart. But if we could get that lifetime specifier to work, we could build a pretty good `StreamingIterator` library. This is just the minimal example that's left us scratching our heads.

Comment: I believe this would be fixed with something like HRL (higher rank lifetimes), where you could have (hypothetical syntax) `trait StreamingIterator<T<'*>> { fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> T<'a>; }`. We don't have the ability to express exactly that now, though.

Comment: ([It was pointed out](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15067#issuecomment-57933614) that I misused terminology: the above should say "HKL (higher kinded lifetimes)".)

Answer (score 3):

The following is an extension of Francis's answer using implicit lifetimes but it allows for the return value to be lifetime bound:

```
pub trait TraitNothing<'a> {
    fn change_it(&mut self);

    fn nothing(&mut self) -> &Self {
        self.change_it();
        self
    }

    fn bounded_nothing(&'a mut self) -> &'a Self {
        self.nothing()
    }

    fn twice_nothing(&'a mut self) -> &'a Self {
        // uncomment to show old fail
        // self.bounded_nothing();
        // self.bounded_nothing()
        self.nothing();
        self.nothing()
    }
}
```

It's less than perfect, but you can call the methods with implicit lifetimes `change_it` and `nothing` multiple times within other methods. I don't know if this will solve your real problem because ultimately `self` has the generic type `&mut Self` in the trait methods whereas in the struct it has type `&mut StructNothing` and the compiler can't guarantee that `Self` doesn't contain a reference. This workaround does solve the code example.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the lifetime parameters on each method rather than on the trait itself, [it compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5769556d8eb409744982422c6d694854):

```
pub trait TraitNothing {
    fn nothing<'a>(&'a mut self) -> () {}

    fn twice_nothing<'a>(&'a mut self) -> () {
        self.nothing();
        self.nothing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not allow the return value to be bounded by `'a`, as is required for the real problem @emk is trying to solve.

Comment: I knew there was a gotcha. But why, exactly? Also, I just tried putting `<'a>` on the trait and `<'b: 'a>` on the methods, but I just get back to the original problem. What does `<'a>` on a trait actually mean?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody seemed to answer the "why?" so here I am.

Here's the point: *In the trait, we're calling methods from the same trait. However, in the free impl, we're not calling methods from the same impl*.

What? Surely we call methods from the same impl?

Let's be more precise: we're calling methods from the same impl, *but not with the same generic parameters*.

Your free impl is essentially equivalent to the following:

```rust
impl StructNothing {
    fn nothing<'a>(&'a mut self) {}

    fn twice_nothing<'a>(&'a mut self) {
        self.nothing();
        self.nothing();
    }
}
```

Because the impl's generic lifetime is floating, it can be chosen separately for each method. The compiler does not call `<Self<'a>>::nothing(self)`, but rather it calls `<Self<'some_shorter_lifetime>>::nothing(&mut *self)`.

With the trait, on the other hand, the situation is completely different. The only thing we can know for sure is that `Self: Trait<'b>`. We cannot call `nothing()` with a shorter lifetime, *because maybe `Self` doesn't implement `Trait` with the shorter lifetime*. Therefore, we are forced to call `<Self as Trait<'a>>::nothing(self)`, and the result is that we're borrowing for overlapping regions.

From this we can infer that if we tell the compiler that `Self` implements `Trait` for *any* lifetime it will work:

```rust
fn twice_nothing(&'a mut self)
where
    Self: for<'b> TraitNothing<'b>,
{
    (&mut *self).nothing();
    (&mut *self).nothing();
}
```

...except it fails to compile because of [issue #84435](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/84435), so I don't know whether this would have succeeded :(

Answer (score -4):

Is this really surprising?

The assertion you're making is that `&mut self` lasts for at least the lifetime `'a`.

In the former case, `&mut self` is a pointer to a struct. No pointer aliasing occurs because the borrow is entirely contained in `nothing()`.

In the latter case, the `&mut self` is a pointer *to a pointer* to a struct + a vtable for the trait. You're locking the pointed to struct that implements `TraitNothing` for the duration of `'a`; i.e. the whole function each time.

By removing `'a`, you're implicitly using `'static`, which says the impl lasts forever, so its fine.

If you want to work around it, transmute the `&'a TraitNothing` to `&'static TraitNothing`... but I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to do.

This is why we need block scopes (`'b: { .... }`) in Rust...

[Try using dummy lifetimes perhaps?](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5813c0047e4e624469cd628eb2d0a2b4)

Comment: The `&mut self` in the trait declaration is not a trait object; it is just a plain pointer to whatever value implements that trait. (Even if it was a `&mut TraitNothing` trait object, it would just be a pointer to a struct + a pointer to the vtable, without the extra layer of indirection.)

Comment: @dbaupp oh really? I thought trait &self implementations were done via something like http://is.gd/Gl20OQ

Comment: @Doug, no, they're not; a default implementation for a method is the same as just writing that code in each `impl`, including being statically dispatched.