Access mutable borrows in a default trait implementation
I want to access and manipulate active_outer_index_iterator and current_outer_index within trait ISequentialOuterIndexRemoverV1. They will be used in function load_outer_index() which is a default trait implementation.
Since this trait will also be applied on another struct with different inner fields, I am not implementing load_outer_index() directly on SequentialOuterIndexRemover.
/// Helper to sequentially read and remove outer indices from the index list
/// in slot storage
pub struct SequentialOuterIndexRemover<'a> {
    /// Iterator to read active outer indices from index list
    pub active_outer_index_iterator: ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2<'a>,

    /// The currently read outer index
    pub current_outer_index: Option<OuterIndex>,
}

pub trait ISequentialOuterIndexRemoverV1<'a> {
    fn active_outer_index_iterator(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2;

    fn current_outer_index(&mut self) -> &mut Option<OuterIndex>;
}

So far I tried two solutions:
Case 1
I added load_outer_index() to the trait and tried to access active_outer_index_iterator() and current_outer_index(). I am getting error 'cannot borrow *self as mutable more than once at a time'.


pub trait ISequentialOuterIndexRemoverV1<'a> {
    fn active_outer_index_iterator(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2;

    fn current_outer_index(&mut self) -> &mut Option<OuterIndex>;

    // Error
    // rustc: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
    // second mutable borrow occurs here
    fn load_outer_index(&'a mut self, ctx: &mut ArbContext) {
        *self.current_outer_index() = self.active_outer_index_iterator().next(ctx);
    }
}

Case 2
I tried the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26194992/27713386. I removed <'a> from top of the trait and added it to the function. The trait compiles but now I am unable to write implementation for active_outer_index_iterator(). I am puzzled with the compiler error because both signatures seem to be the same.
rustc: method not compatible with trait
expected signature `fn(&'a mut SequentialOuterIndexRemover<'_>) -> &'a mut ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2<'a>`
   found signature `fn(&'a mut SequentialOuterIndexRemover<'_>) -> &'a mut ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2<'a>`

pub trait ISequentialOuterIndexRemover {
    // <'a> removed from above and added to this function
    fn active_outer_index_iterator<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &mut ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2;

    fn current_outer_index(&mut self) -> &mut Option<OuterIndex>;


    // Works now
    fn load_outer_index<'a>(&'a mut self, ctx: &mut ArbContext) {
        *self.current_outer_index() = self.active_outer_index_iterator().next(ctx);
    }
}

impl<'a> ISequentialOuterIndexRemover for SequentialOuterIndexRemover<'a> {
    // rustc: method not compatible with trait
    // expected signature `fn(&'a mut SequentialOuterIndexRemover<'_>) -> &'a mut ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2<'a>`
    //    found signature `fn(&'a mut SequentialOuterIndexRemover<'_>) -> &'a mut ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2<'a>`
    fn active_outer_index_iterator<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &mut ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2 {
        &mut self.active_outer_index_iterator
    }

    fn current_outer_index(&mut self) -> &mut Option<OuterIndex> {
        &mut self.current_outer_index
    }
}

Edit 1
As pointed by Jmb, I forgot to add lifetime <'a> on the method when posting the question. The issue persists even after editing.
Edit 2- minimum reproducible example
struct InnerStruct<'a> {
    data: &'a mut u8,
}

struct MyStruct<'a> {
    inner: InnerStruct<'a>,
    cache: u8,
}

trait GetInnerMut<'a> {
    fn get_inner_mut(&'a mut self) -> &mut InnerStruct;

    fn get_cache(&mut self) -> &mut u8;

    fn process(&'a mut self) {
        let inner_mut = self.get_inner_mut();
        // rustc: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
        // second mutable borrow occurs here
        *self.get_cache() = *inner_mut.data;
    }
}

impl<'a> GetInnerMut<'a> for MyStruct<'a> {
    fn get_inner_mut(&'a mut self) -> &mut InnerStruct {
        &mut self.inner
    }

    fn get_cache(&mut self) -> &mut u8 {
        &mut self.cache
    }
}


In the case 2 implementation the lifetime should be on the method, not the whole impl.

With ISequentialOuterIndexRemoverV1<'a> and fn load_outer_index(&'a mut self, ctx: &mut ArbContext), you essentially borrow self forever.

It's hard to tell with missing type definitions. Please provide a [mre]. Your code likely doesn't need lifetime annotations at all.

@kmdreko please check updated question for MRE

Why do you use a referenced string? String  is a kind of pointer itself, it points to the heap where the actual string data is. Without a reference, there wouldn't be any need to care about lifetimes.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? You code look a bit like a translation from Java or C++. Usually, Rust requires to overthink the used data structures to achieve the same as in another language.

@Matthias my actual code holds a mutable reference to a number. I'm updating the example to use &'a mut u8, but the problem still stands.

@Matthias I have these structs with common fields.
pub struct SequentialOuterIndexRemover<'a> {
    pub active_outer_index_iterator: ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2<'a>,
    pub current_outer_index: Option<OuterIndex>,
}

pub struct RandomOuterIndexRemover<'a> {
    pub active_outer_index_iterator: ActiveOuterIndexIteratorV2<'a>,
    pub current_outer_index: Option<OuterIndex>,
    pub cached_outer_indices: Vec<OuterIndex>,
}

Trying to avoid nesting SequentialOuterIndexRemover. The stuct holding RandomOuterIndexRemover needs functions belonging to both these removers.

tldr I can nest SequentialOuterIndexRemover inside RandomOuterIndexRemover and avoid traits. I thought that sharing a trait with a default implemented function was cleaner.

@grfs thanks for the minimal example, it made it a lot easier to diagnose. The main problem is you're returning &mut InnerStruct which is inferred as &'a mut InnerStruct<'a>, which is almost always a problem.

You stuck the 'a lifetime in the wrong spot. It parameterizes InnerStruct, not &mut self. You can kind of see this if you peel back the layers: the lifetime of &mut self.inner is obviously the same as that of &mut self, but the data contained therein has the separate lifetime of 'a.
struct InnerStruct<'a> {
    data: &'a mut u8,
}

struct MyStruct<'a> {
    inner: InnerStruct<'a>,
    cache: u8,
}

trait GetInnerMut<'a> {
    fn get_inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut InnerStruct<'a>;
}

impl<'a> GetInnerMut<'a> for MyStruct<'a> {
    fn get_inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut InnerStruct<'a> {
        &mut self.inner
    }
}

